# Deploy quietly to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to release a public application through Google Play without any public notification?  We want to publish an app on Google Play that isn't seen by any marketing robots that generate "What's New in Android"-type articles.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to release a public application through Google Play without any public notification?

No. There are *private* deployment options, such as for enterprise apps. But if the public can access it, then you have no means of preventing "marketing robots" from accessing it, any more than you can prevent people of races, religions, political parties, or anything else you don't like from accessing it.

You're welcome to attempt to pressure Google to cut off access to these "marketing robots", which use undocumented, unsupported, and possibly unauthorized means of determining "what's new". I have lobbied to either make this capability officially allowed or officially disallowed, rather than have it reside in the grey area that it does presently, to no avail.